# Storm KafkaSpout failed tuples duplicated

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I am using storm-kafka-1.1.1-plus and storm 1.1.1. And configured **using BaseRichBolt,  one KafkaSpout and two bolts bolt-A, Bolt-B** the tuples are **anchored in bolt-A once the bolt-B acknowledged it will be considered as a successfully processed tuple** and it will be committed. But, the problem is for some reason some **failed message got duplicated in KafkaSpout**.

**For Example**

KafkaSpout emitted 1000 tuples while processing it for some reason nearly 20 tuples were got failed (at bolt-B ). those 20 tuples were replays continuously, at some point worker got killed and supervisor restarts the worker and again those 20 tuples were replays and this time it successfully processed but it processed multiple times( duplicated ).

[image]

But, I want those tuples must be processed only once (successfully). I have set the **topology.enable.message.timeouts as false**. And my another question is **where does the Storm stores those failed Kafka offset details**. I didn't find it on zookeeper it only has below detail.

{"topology":{"id":"test_Topology-12-1508938595","name":"test_Topology"},"offset":505,"partition":2,"broker":{"host":"127.0.0.1","port":9092},"topic":"test_topic_1"}

Answer (score 2):

Disabling message timeouts can cause message loss, you may want to reconsider disabling it if you need all messages to be processed.

Storm provides an at-least-once processing guarantee when acking is enabled. You might want to look at whether you can make your bolts idempotent so replays don't cause you issues. Alternatively you can look at https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.1.1/Trident-tutorial.html, which offers exactly-once state updates.

Edit:
You might need to rethink your problem. As far as I'm aware no stream processing system offers exactly-once processing in the sense it sounds like you want.

The exactly-once semantics offered by Trident are that Trident will help you make state updates idempotent, so it will "look like" the messages are only processed once, from the point of view of your data store. Processing is still at-least-once. See the section "Transactional spouts" (and probably the rest of the page) at https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Trident-state.html for the intuition about how this would work. The basic idea is to store information in the data store about which messages have already been written, that way if they are repeated the state update code can ignore them.

You might also want to read https://streaml.io/blog/exactly-once. I want to say that Flink implements something like the distributed snapshot algorithm described there, which is a different way to simulate exactly-once in an at-least-once system.

Comment: Apologies for the delay.. as per my problem each and every message is unique and must be a valid one and it has to be processed only once until it got success. Will Trident spout wok for above prob or can you suggest anything else?

Comment: And important thing is "message should not be processed more than once" and it should process even after the worker stop and start in between processing

Comment: Edited the original post, the addition was too long for a comment.

Comment: this is very useful info for me